# psycopg.OperationalError: connection failed: password authentication failed for user "awx"

Tags: docker, ansible, kubernetes

Running into an error with my Ansible AWX local setup. This was working before but, after I recreated the pods when trying to debug another issue, I now get the error `psycopg.OperationalError: connection failed: password authentication failed for user "awx"` in my ansible-awx-web pod.

I read on a forum that deleting the PVC and applying the AWX manifest again solves the issue but that's not the case for me.

```
Awx-Operator version 2.9.0
Kubernetes v1.28.2
```

**awx.yaml (without secret)**

```
---
apiVersion: awx.ansible.com/v1beta1
kind: AWX
metadata:
  name: ansible-awx
  namespace: awx
spec:
  service_type: nodeport
  postgres_storage_class: local-storage
```

Without explistly listing db user/password in a secret file

kubectl get pods -n awx

```
NAME                                               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS       AGE
ansible-awx-postgres-13-0                          1/1     Running            0              14h
ansible-awx-task-cd6c58fc6-qh5j6                   4/4     Running            0              18h
ansible-awx-web-86f59df-h9mtg                      2/3     CrashLoopBackOff   89 (96s ago)   18h
awx-operator-controller-manager-5bcd47d577-598rp   2/2     Running            0              18h
```

**awx.yaml with secret**

```
apiVersion: awx.ansible.com/v1beta1
kind: AWX
metadata:
  name: ansible-awx
  namespace: awx
spec:
  service_type: nodeport
  postgres_storage_class: local-storage
  postgres_configuration_secret: awx-postgres-configuration
```

**secret.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: awx-postgres-configuration
  namespace: awx
stringData:
  database: "awx"
  username: "awx"
  password: {{password}}
  sslmode: prefer
  type: unmanaged
type: Opaque
```

With the secret if i run kubectl get pods -n awx, I can only get awx-operator pod to run. What am i doing wrong with my secret?

```
NAME                                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
awx-operator-controller-manager-5bcd47d577-lscqf   2/2     Running   0          2m20s
```

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48999379/psycopg2-operationalerror-fatal-password-authentication-failed-for-user-my-u) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i solved my issue, I think somewhere along the way I changed something in the pods and it corrupted my set up. I ended up uninstalling Docker Desktop and reinstalling along with Enabling Kubernetes to get a fresh set up now the pods are running fine again.

Answer (score -1):

the error you are getting is the PostgreSQL database credentials.
`--user awx ALTER USER awx WITH PASSWORD 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';`psql